# Can't solve this SQL query

Tags: postgresql

I have a difficulty dealing with a SQL query. I use PostgreSQL.

The query says: Show the customers that have done at least an order that contains products from 3 different categories. The result will be 2 columns, `CustomerID`, and the amount of orders. I have written this code but I don't think it's correct.

```
select SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID,
       count(SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID) AS amount_of_orders
from SalesOrderHeader 
inner join SalesOrderDetail on
       (SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID)
inner join Product on 
       (SalesOrderDetail.ProductID=Product.ProductID)

where SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderDetailID in 
       (select DISTINCT count(ProductCategoryID)
        from Product
        group by ProductCategoryID
        having count(DISTINCT ProductCategoryID)>=3)

group by SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

Here are the database tables needed for the query:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No but according to the records given the output isn't logical

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

```
where SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderDetailID in 
             (select DISTINCT count(ProductCategoryID)
```

Is never going to give you a result as an ID (`SalesOrderDetailID`) will never logically match a `COUNT` (`count(ProductCategoryID)`).

This should get you the output I think you want.

```
SELECT soh.CustomerID, COUNT(soh.SalesOrderID) AS amount_of_orders
FROM SalesOrderHeader soh
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail sod ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Product p ON sod.ProductID = p.ProductID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductCategoryID) >= 3
GROUP BY soh.CustomerID
```

Comment: I execute it and  I took a look at the data(there are too many records in the db)I think the output is not correct

Comment: Plus the output in some rows gives 55 product categories when there are only 37 in the data given

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select CustomerID,count(*) as amount_of_order from 
  SalesOrder join 
 (
   select SalesOrderID,count(distinct ProductCategoryID) CategoryCount 
     from SalesOrderDetail JOIN Product using (ProductId)
  group by 1
 ) CatCount using (SalesOrderId) 
 group by 1 
 having bool_or(CategoryCount>=3) -- At least on CategoryCount>=3
```