# SQL Select query for Select 3 different products

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Good Evening,

I've been struggling with a select query on my database on which I want to determine the clients that have placed an order of 3 products from at least 3 different product categories.
Then I want to print the CustomerID and the number of the orders.

This is my Database diagram:
[image: Database for bike company design]

Any Answer would be helpful,

Sincerely Thanos.

Comment: Please clarify - do you want the customers who ordered at least 3 products from different categories in a single order?  What is the "number of orders" you want to see in the result set?  The total number of orders for each customer, the number of matching orders, the ordered quantities of the products in matching orders, or something else?  Do you expect a row per customer or a row per order or something else in the result set?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
For all clients that have made at least one order that consisted of products of 3 different categories print customerid and number of orders with at least 3 product categories.

Comment: Is it an homework ? look at this : ["Can't solve this SQL query"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745429/cant-solve-this-sql-query/37746019#37746019 )

Comment: Yes it actually is!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe it should be close to correct:

```
SELECT h.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT h.SalesOrderID)
FROM SalesOrderHeader h
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail d1 ON h.SalesOrderID = d1.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail d2 ON h.SalesOrderID = d2.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail d3 ON h.SalesOrderID = d3.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Product p1 ON d1.ProductID = p1.ProductID
INNER JOIN Product p2 ON d2.ProductID = p2.ProductID
INNER JOIN Product p3 ON d3.ProductID = p3.ProductID
WHERE p1.ProductCategoryID <> p2.ProductCategoryID
  AND p2.ProductCategoryID <> p3.ProductCategoryID
  AND p1.ProductCategoryID <> p3.ProductCategoryID
GROUP BY h.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerId, count(*)
from(
  select CustomerId
  from SalesOrderHeader soh
  join SalesOrderDetail sod using (SalesOrderID)
  join Product p using (ProductId)
  group by CustomerId, SalesOrderId
  having count(distinct ProductCategoryID) > 2
) a
group by CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you the result

```
Select CustomerID,SalesOrderID , count(CategoryID) CatCount  
From 
SalesOrderHeader Head inner join SalesOrderDetail Det 
on Head.SalesOrderID = Det.SalesOrderID
inner join Product Prod
on Prod.ProductID = Det.ProductID
inner join ProductCategory PCat
on Prod.CategoryID = PCat.CategoryID
Group By CustomerID,SalesOrderID
Having count(CategoryID) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

like for : "Can't solve this SQL query"

```
select CustomerID,count(*) as amount_of_order from 
SalesOrder join 
(
   select SalesOrderID,count(distinct ProductCategoryID) CategoryCount 
   from SalesOrderDetail JOIN Product using (ProductId)
   group by 1
 ) CatCount using (SalesOrderId) 
 group by 1 
 having bool_or(CategoryCount>=3) -- At least on CategoryCount>=3
```